# T-SQL : Fetch records based on two conditions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-administration

[image]

I want to fetch the records from one SQL Server database table based on two conditions,

1. Having "final_qs" value "NA"
2. Skip the "final_qs" value "NA" having "NOTHING_TO_TEST_LAST_4_AUDIT" as a "Status"

In this I have written query which will filter the records based on "final_qs" as "NA", but I stuck for the second case mentioned above.

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear. First, sample data should be posted as DDL+DML (create table and insert statement(s)). Second, you should also post expected results. Third, you should also post your current attempts.

Answer (score 2):

You should use "OR" and "AND" Operators, Like this code:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable
WHERE final_qs = 'NA'
OR (final_qs <> 'NA' AND status = 'NOTHING_TO_TEST_LAST_4_AUDIT')
```

Comment: This can be simplified to `WHERE final_qs = 'NA' or  status = 'NOTHING_TO_TEST_LAST_4_AUDIT'`